# For loop using a t-stat function to create a list

Tags: list, r

I am using the following function to calculate the t-stat for data in data frame (x):

```
    wilcox.test.all.genes<-function(x,s1,s2) {
     x1<-x[s1]
     x2<-x[s2]
     x1<-as.numeric(x1)
     x2<-as.numeric(x2)
     wilcox.out<-wilcox.test(x1,x2,exact=F,alternative="two.sided",correct=T)
     out<-as.numeric(wilcox.out$statistic)
     return(out)
    }
```

I need to write a for loop that will iterate a specific number of times.  For each iteration, the columns need to be shuffled, the above function performed and the maximum t-stat value saved to a list.

I know that I can use the `sample()` function to shuffle the columns of the data frame, and the `max()` function to identify the maximum t-stat value, but I can't figure out how to put them together to achieve a workable code.

Comment: The answer below works, but I'm still a bit unclear on what you're actually trying to do. Comparing your real test statistic to the distribution output from these permutations will give you an empiric p-value. However, you mention taking the max, which is usually done to correct for the multiple comparisons if you are doing many of these similar tests. My confusion though is that your x is a vector, and you are only performing a single test. Anyway, if you clarify a bit, I'm happy to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The data frame that I am using has data from two classes of individuals, I am splitting the data based on class.  The function is a Wilcox test on the data from the two classes.  After the initial test is completed, I want to shuffle the columns of the data frame, perform the function again, obtain the max test statistic from the new data and save this number into a list.  I want to perform the shuffling 500 times resulting in a list of 500 max test stats from the shuffled data.  I will be using this list of test stats to determine a 95% test stat for comparison to the original dataset. thanks

Comment: I see. That's what I thought. It would have helped if you provided example data, as we had no way of knowing that you had a data frame. Also, there is a bit of confusion because for doing permutation testing like this, you permute the class labels (i.e. the *rows*), and not the columns. See my edited answer below for your solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to generate empiric p-values, corrected for the multiple comparisons you are making because of the multiple columns in your data. First, let's simulate an example data set:

```
# Simulate data
n.row = 100
n.col = 10

set.seed(12345)
group = factor(sample(2, n.row, replace=T))
data  = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n.row*n.col), nrow=n.row))
```

Calculate the Wilcoxon test for each column, but we will replicate this many times while permuting the class membership of the observations. This gives us an empiric null distribution of this test statistic.

```
# Re-calculate columnwise test statisitics many times while permuting class labels
perms = replicate(500, apply(data[sample(nrow(data)), ], 2, function(x) wilcox.test(x[group==1], x[group==2], exact=F, alternative="two.sided", correct=T)$stat))
```

Calculate the null distribution of the *maximum* test statistic by collapsing across the multiple comparisons.

```
# For each permuted replication, calculate the max test statistic across the multiple comparisons
perms.max = apply(perms, 2, max)
```

By simply sorting the results, we can now determine the p=0.05 critical value.

```
# Identify critical value 
crit = sort(perms.max)[round((1-0.05)*length(perms.max))]
```

We can also plot our distribution along with the critical value.

```
# Plot 
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
hist(perms.max)
abline(v=crit, col='red')
```

[image]

Finally, comparing a real test statistic to this distribution will give you an empiric p-value, corrected for multiple comparisons by controlling the family-wise error to p<0.05. For example, let's pretend a real test stat was 1600. We could then calculate the p-value like:

```
> length(which(perms.max>1600))/length(perms.max)
[1] 0.074
```